# Placing a matrix in echelon form with the Eigen library

Tags: eigen, eigen3

This post concerns very short, wide arrays (# columns can be several orders of magnitude larger than the number of rows).

Due to the disparity in row/column number and the large size of the matrices I work with, it's usually infeasible to hold the U part of an LU decomposition in memory.  Does Eigen have functionality to compute just the L?  Equivalently, to place the input matrix in echelon form using row operations?

General notes

(1) I saw a related question here

https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=138686&p=371097&hilit=echelon#p371097

The answer suggested looking at the image() method under FullPivLU, but I wasn't able to find the necessary information in the docs.  In particular, it's often important to obtain the matrix L, in practice.  An arbitrary basis for the column space of the matrix does not suffice.

(2) There was another question here

https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=130430&p=348923&hilit=echelon#p348923

but it did not seem to get a response.

(3) Issues of stability are of less concern in the (fairly specialized) application domain that motivates this question, since we usually work over finite fields.

Thanks!